# Mysql result include e+07, how can we escape e+07 from the result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If i export the result from mysql to csv file all value is shown normal, once i execute select command from mysql the result shown as x.xxxxxe+07

Exp:

```
select mycolumn from mytable where mycolumn=25744130;
```

The result as following

```
2.57441e+07
2.57441e+07
2.57441e+07
...
```

Is there any way to avoid such kind display?

Comment: Try creating a view with this column instead `cast(mycolumn as char(8))` and export the view

Comment: @Bohemian `CAST` to `CHAR` unfortunately will fail: `select v, cast(v as CHAR) from t;` will result in `2.57441e17 | 2.57441e17` for example

Comment: @Bohemian thank you for advice, i tried `cast(mycolumn as char(8))` it gives me result as `2.57441e`

Comment: Where are you seeing this result?  Is it after you open the file in Excel, or in the CSV file itself>

Comment: @Jim Garrison, both in Excel and CSV file itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - please, note, that in common case it's not true to say that, for example, `2.57441e17` is `257441000000000000` - because of lack of significant digits. Also, in such case you won't be able to say something certain about fractional part.

Assuming that you want to output zero-filled result without fractional part, you can use [`FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(f, 0), ',', '') FROM t
```

like:

```
mysql> SELECT v, replace(format(v, 0), ',', '') FROM t;
+------------+--------------------------------+
| v          | replace(format(v, 0), ',', '') |
+------------+--------------------------------+
| 2.57441e17 | 257441000000000000             |
+------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

this will result in string value, but for CSV all values actually are strings (so it's a matter of interpretation).

Comment: Thank you so much, it gives me just what i wanted. appreciate your help.